# How to disable camera access option in Windows 11?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-11

I need to disable the selected camera access option in Windows 11 using C#. Is there any option for that?
[image]

Comment: You do that with a group policy Administrative Templates - Windows Components - App Privacy - Let Windows apps access the camera. You do not do that with C# because it's then not for you to mess with.